# ASP.net Ajax UpdatePanel Child Control's Visibility Issue

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, visibility

I want to change the visibility of two asp.net image controls (runat="server") at the beginning and the end of the method call duration. I mean, I want the first image displayed and second one remains hidden until the last line of my method, which in turn, the second image becomes visible and the first one hides.
I've put the area of the triggering control in updatepanel and have declared triggers of the updatepanel; But when I press the control (which is a button), the image at the end of the process is displayed correctly and on time but the one which should be displayed in the first line of the method is not displayed. I've configured my updatepanel to use conditional update mode and have used these lines for my intention:

```
imgLoading.Visible = true;

    ..
    rest of the process
    ..

    if (true)
    {
        imgLoading.Visible = false;
        imgSuccess.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: my guess is you'll have to do that in javascript as the page load will only run the code and refresh the browser. Which means your first image gets set back to false when the server refreshes the page.

Comment: Thank you for your care Mr. Andrew. So does embedding the updatepanel in another updaterpanel can help?

Comment: have you registered your control that you are using for trigger

Comment: Yes I am dear mehul. Everything is good but I can not change the visibility 2 times, once at the start of the routine and once at the final line of the routine.

Comment: Of course these changes in visibility affect two images, at first it shows one and hides the other and at last hides the first one and shows the other.

Comment: ok. so just for debugging, try to comment the last line where you set visibility to false

Comment: when i configure the method to show the final image it correctly does but when i ask it to first show an image then start the method commands and finally hide the "currently processing" icon and show the "well done" icon it can not show the first operation.

Comment: You can try Thread.Sleep() before your if(true) block, may be the execution of code is not taking much time.

Comment: Dear mehul, my process includes a heavy database operation which incorporates about 10sec to complete. However I'd test your advice and again, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot switch to the image loading from the server because everything happens in one request, so what's rendered doesn't occur until the very end; it will never know that the loading image was set to visible true.  So you can use JavaScript.

Or since you are using the UpdatePanel, use the UpdateProgress control, which displays something over the update panel when an update is occurring.  This control is meant to do exactly this.

See this: http://weblogs.asp.net/stoianbucovich/archive/2008/01/30/asp-net-2-0-ajax-update-panel-and-update-progress.aspx

HTH.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Brian. You pointed out the true solution. It is only one request and I used updateprogress instead.